# Need help on LMGTFY(Search) command for discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a LMGTFY (Search) command. I want the bot to replace space with a + so instead of the bot saying *https://lmgtfy.app/?q=test 1* I want it to say, *https://lmgtfy.app/?q=test+1*. Im new to python so Im sorry if this sounds like a very easy question to solve.

Here's my code:

````py
@commands.command(aliases=["google"])
  async def search(self, ctx, *, link): 
    await ctx.send(f"https://lmgtfy.app/?q={link}")```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace()` for this:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["google"])
async def search(self, ctx, *, link): 
    await ctx.send(f"https://lmgtfy.app/?q={link.replace(' ', '+')}")
```

Comment: If this is the solution of your question, you should accept this as an answer.